# SUM LOOKUPVALUE with condition

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like some help figuring out some DAX in Power BI.

I’ve included two screenshots of some mock tables I created in Excel to provide context. I have one master table called **Financials** which has all of the financial transactions associated with a claim number. I have another table called **Test** which is built from the Financials table.

The **Test** table contains the distinct values of claim numbers since in the **Financials** table a claim number can have multiple transactions. In the event that a claim number has multiple transactions, it would be on separate rows, as shown in the screenshot. Below is the formula I used to create my **Test** table with distinct claim numbers.

```
Test Table = distinct(Financials[Claim Number])
```

**My Request**
In reference to the screenshot for the attached Test table, I would like to create two columns titled Investigation and Settlement. In plain English, I would like the DAX formula to sum the check amount if the payment type in the Financials table is Investigation. The same logic would apply when payment type is Settlement. In the end I will have one column for Investigation and one column for Settlement, as shown in the **Test** table image.

I’m thinking something like: `if lookupvalue from payment type in Financials = 'investigation' then sum check amount.`  Also, not sure if I would use SUM or SUMX.

The **Test** table will then have one row for each claim and it will have summed up all of the investigation payments and all of the settlement payments for the related claim from the **Financials** table.

Thank you for any help.  I'm sure it's easy yet I can't figure it out!

[image: Financials]

[image: Test]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new table and write this code:

```
test_table = 
    SUMMARIZE(
        financial_table,
        financial_table[Claim Number],
        financial_table[Claim Status],
        financial_table[Date Closed],
        financial_table[Legal],
       "Investigation", CALCULATE(
                            SUM(financial_table[Check Amount]),
                            financial_table[Payment Type]="Investigation"
                        )+0,
       "Settlement", CALCULATE(
                         SUM(financial_table[Check Amount]),
                         financial_table[Payment Type]="Settlement"
                     )+0
    )
```